# how to configure haproxy to publish website with substring to real backend server

Tags: haproxy

the real published website of the backend server is  192.168.1.6:8888/abc and 192.168.1.7:8888/abc , 
The ip of haproxy is 192.168.1.5 , how can I set in haproxy that user visit 192.168.1.5:8888/abc, the http request will be forwarded to the real backend server(192.168.1.6:8888/abc and 192.168.1.7:8888/abc) ? 
the default backend server is 192.168.1.8:8088 and 192.168.1.9. (a default nginx website)

+++++++++++++ My configuration is +++++++++++++++

frontend case3
    bind 192.168.1.5:8888

```
acl abc path_beg -i /abc

use_backend abc_servers if abc  

default_backend nginx1
```

backend abc_servers

```
mode tcp

balance roundrobin

server abc1 192.168.1.6:8888 cookie 

server abc2 192.168.1.7:8888 cookie
```

backend nginx1

```
balance roundrobin

server master1 192.168.1.8:8888 maxconn 1024 weight 5 check

server master2 192.168.1.9:80 maxconn 1024 weight 5 check
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

after it take effect, 
when i visit  192.168.1.5:8888 , it can visit the first server of nginx1.
but when i visit 192.168.1.5:8888/abc, it reports :

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
         404 Not Found
         nginx/1.17.9
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Are you sure HaProxy is running with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

A rudimentary configuration would look as follows:

```
frontend web.jerrywang.org
    bind 192.168.1.5:8888
    use_backend api_servers if { path_beg /abc/ }
    # default_backend web_servers  # The users will get 503 for anything else

backend api_servers
    balance roundrobin
    cookie SERVERUSED insert indirect nocache
    option httpchk HEAD /
    default-server check maxconn 20
    server server1 192.168.1.6:8888 cookie server1
    server server2 192.168.1.7:8888 cookie server2
```

Comment: thanks for your post,  i don't know why i get 404 error

Comment: Why the "mode tcp" for the abc_servers backend?  And shouldn't you specify a name for the server cookies?